# Oracle SQL Developer -- Is there a way to reload past fiter parameters that I have specified

Tags: filtering, oracle-sqldeveloper

When examining a table, there is a filter field.  Sometimes I put some lengthy filter parameters in there.  Is it possible to see past parameters I have specified, and load them into the Filter field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so. SQL Developer's filter offers just a *single line* of a filter.

Just as an illustration, **TOAD** lets you do that because its filter looks more like an "Editor" window, so you can put several filters in there and (un)comment them as you want:

[image]